# nhibernate using icriteria with a group by and having, and getting total row count (c#)

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, c#-3.0

So I have an nhibernate icriteria query that gets the list of results that I want.

However I cannot figure out how to get the total row count.

```
public IEnumerable<SpecialismCombo> List(SpecialismListCriteria criteria, out int total)
        {
            //run the sub query
            ICriteria countAgencies = m_SpecialismComboRepository.QueryAlias("sc");

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.AgencyIds) && !criteria.AgencyIds.Equals("0"))
            {
                List<int> AgencyIds = criteria.AgencyIds.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList<int>();
                countAgencies.CreateAlias("Agencies", "a", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);
                countAgencies.Add(Restrictions.In("a.AgencyId", AgencyIds));
            }

            total = Convert.ToInt32(
              countAgencies.SetProjection(
                  Projections.CountDistinct("a.AgencyId")
              ).UniqueResult()
            );


            //create query
            ICriteria query = m_SpecialismComboRepository.QueryAlias("sc");

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.AgencyIds) && !criteria.AgencyIds.Equals("0"))
            {
                List<int> AgencyIds = criteria.AgencyIds.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList<int>();
                query.CreateAlias("Agencies", "a", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);
                query.Add(Restrictions.In("a.AgencyId", AgencyIds));
            }

            query.Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Count("SpecialismComboId"),total));

            ProjectionList pl = Projections.ProjectionList()
                       .AddPropertyAlias("SpecialismComboId", "SpecialismComboId")
                       .AddPropertyAlias("SpecialismComboDisplayText", "SpecialismComboDisplayText")
                       .AddPropertyAlias("SpecialismComboDisciplineDisplayText", "SpecialismComboDisciplineDisplayText")
                       .AddPropertyAlias("SpecialismComboIdText", "SpecialismComboIdText")
                       .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("SpecialismComboId"));

            // set the right total for records being returned
            total = query.ToRowCount();

            // Return the query results
            return query
               .SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(
                   pl
               ))
               .SetResultTransformer(new KnownPropertyAliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(SpecialismCombo)))
               .SetFirstResult(criteria.FirstRecord)
               .SetMaxResults(criteria.PageSize)
               .List<SpecialismCombo>() as List<SpecialismCombo>;

        }
```

I was trying to use an ICriteriaExtension we have:

```
public static int ToRowCount(this ICriteria query)
        {
            return query.ToRowCountQuery().UniqueResult<int>();
        }
```

But it returns null.

so the query generated in SQL is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT distinct top 15 this_.SpecialismComboId as y0_, 
(select dbo.fn_GetSpecialismComboDisplayText(this_.SpecialismComboId,''/'')) as y1_, 
(select dbo.fn_GetSpecialismComboDisciplineDisplayText(this_.SpecialismComboId,'', '')) as y2_, 
(select dbo.fn_GetSpecialismComboIdText(this_.SpecialismComboId,''|'')) as y3_, 
this_.SpecialismComboId as y4_ 
FROM dbo.SpecialismCombo this_ 
inner join AgencySpecialismCombo agencies3_ on this_.SpecialismComboId=agencies3_.SpecialismComboId 
inner join dbo.Agency a1_ on agencies3_.AgencyId=a1_.AgencyId WHERE a1_.AgencyId in (@p0) 
GROUP BY this_.SpecialismComboId HAVING count(this_.SpecialismComboId) = @p1',N'@p0 int,@p1 int',@p0=4741,@p1=1
```

The Row Count based on my above code is

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT top 2147483647 count(*) as y0_ 
FROM dbo.SpecialismCombo this_ 
inner join AgencySpecialismCombo agencies3_ on this_.SpecialismComboId=agencies3_.SpecialismComboId 
inner join dbo.Agency a1_ on agencies3_.AgencyId=a1_.AgencyId WHERE a1_.AgencyId in (@p0) 
HAVING count(this_.SpecialismComboId) = @p1',N'@p0 int,@p1 int',@p0=4741,@p1=1
```

But what I need it to be like is this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT sum(idcount) from 
(select count(*) idcount
FROM dbo.SpecialismCombo this_ 
inner join AgencySpecialismCombo agencies3_ on this_.SpecialismComboId=agencies3_.SpecialismComboId 
inner join dbo.Agency a1_ on agencies3_.AgencyId=a1_.AgencyId WHERE a1_.AgencyId in (@p0) 
GROUP BY this_.SpecialismComboId HAVING count(this_.SpecialismComboId) = @p1) as sub
',N'@p0 int,@p1 int',@p0=4741,@p1=1
```

But once again I can't figure out how to use icriteria (which is what our data access standard is) to get this query and the correct count being returned!!

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Using fluent nhibernate 2.0 I believe.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer a colleague of mine came up with:

```
public IEnumerable<SpecialismCombo> List(SpecialismListCriteria criteria, out int total)
        {
            //create query
            DetachedCriteria query = DetachedCriteria.For<SpecialismCombo>("sc");

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.AgencyIds) && !criteria.AgencyIds.Equals("0"))
            {
                List<int> agencyIds = criteria.AgencyIds.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList<int>();
                query.CreateAlias("Agencies", "a", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);
                query.Add(Restrictions.In("a.AgencyId", agencyIds));

                // Subquery
                var subqueryCount = query
                    .SetProjection(Projections.CountDistinct("a.AgencyId"))
                    .GetExecutableCriteria(NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession())
                    .UniqueResult<int>();

                query.Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Count("SpecialismComboId"), subqueryCount));
            }

            ProjectionList pl = Projections.ProjectionList()
                       .AddPropertyAlias("SpecialismComboId", "SpecialismComboId")
                       .AddPropertyAlias("SpecialismComboDisplayText", "SpecialismComboDisplayText")
                       .AddPropertyAlias("SpecialismComboDisciplineDisplayText", "SpecialismComboDisciplineDisplayText")
                       .AddPropertyAlias("SpecialismComboIdText", "SpecialismComboIdText")
                       .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("SpecialismComboId"));

            total = FullCountQuery(query)
                .GetExecutableCriteria(NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession())
                .ToRowCount();

            // Return the query results
            return query
               .SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(pl))
               .SetResultTransformer(new KnownPropertyAliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(SpecialismCombo)))
               .SetFirstResult(criteria.FirstRecord)
               .SetMaxResults(criteria.PageSize)
               .GetExecutableCriteria(NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession())
               .List<SpecialismCombo>() as List<SpecialismCombo>;

        }

        private DetachedCriteria FullCountQuery(DetachedCriteria query)
        {
            ProjectionList pl = Projections.ProjectionList()
                       .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("SpecialismComboId"));
            var subquery = CriteriaTransformer.Clone(query).SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(pl));

            return DetachedCriteria.For<SpecialismCombo>("sc")
                .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("sc.SpecialismComboId", subquery))
                .SetProjection(Projections.CountDistinct("SpecialismComboId"));
        }
```

I thought I was getting the hang of icriteria and projections and stuff.  But this fullcountquery blew that away :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK in ICriteria you can't specify subqueries in the FROM clause.

Either return the subcounts and sum clientside or resort to HQL or SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It seems disappointing that I have a query that returns the records I want.. but I can't easily get the count of the records of the query without having to write another function or bit of code. But maybe that's just the limitation of icriteria!